# Getting app object pointer in Dialog Message Proc

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers

We can use *this* as the last argument to CreateWindow and get a pointer to the app object in the WndProc like this:

```
if(message == WM_CREATE)
{
    CREATESTRUCT* cs = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
    pApp = (DemoApp*)cs->lpCreateParams;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the best way to access this pointer in a Dialog Message Proc? Is the solution to make a global pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get additional initialization data with `WM_INITDIALOG`, see [WM_INITDIALOG message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> lParam
>
> Additional initialization data. This data is passed to the system
>   as the lParam parameter in a call to the `CreateDialogIndirectParam`,
>   `CreateDialogParam`, `DialogBoxIndirectParam`, or `DialogBoxParam` function
>   used to create the dialog box. For property sheets, this parameter is
>   a pointer to the `PROPSHEETPAGE` structure used to create the page. This
>   parameter is zero if any other dialog box creation function is used.

That is, you can pass `lParam` as an argument with `CreateDialogParam` and the dialog proc will receive it with `WM_INITDIALOG` message.

Comment: This looks like it might be what I need. If I call it from my WndProc, I pass WM_CREATE's lParam and get the pointer the same way. But what if I call it from outside the WndProc. In other words, how do I convert directly from MyClass* to a LPARAM?

Comment: MyClass* pMyClass = ...; CreateDialogParam(..., pMyClass, ...); - is this what you need? Within DialogProc you cast `lParam` back to `MyClass*`.

Comment: Okay. I wasn't sure if I needed reinterpert_cast<> to convert from MyClass* to LPARAM and back. Thanks.

Comment: `lParam` is of pointer compatible type, so you can and need reinterpret_cast your pointer there and back. From within the class it is `this` and outisde it's just a class pointer `pMyClass`.